# XXZ chain exact ground state energy

Tags: integrable-systems, ground-state, spin-chains

I would like to know the analytical expression of the ground state energy of the XXZ model, if such formula exists (probably from a Bethe Ansatz solution) and if it is valid in all parameter regimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such analytical expressions were derived for special cases by multiple authors. More general results were obtained by Yang and Yang in

[C. N. Yang and C. P. Yang *One-Dimensional Chain of Anisotropic Spin-Spin Interactions. II. Properties of the Ground-State Energy Per Lattice Site for an Infinite System*, Phys. Rev. **150**, 327 (1966)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.150.327).

For example, the ground state energy for zero magnetization is specifically addressed in Eqs. (31a-d), and later simplifications in the paper. There, the symbol $f(\Delta,y)$ is used to denote ground state energy at net magnetization $y$. This notation is introduced in the preceding paper, [C. N. Yang and C. P. Yang, Phys. Rev. 150, 321 (1966)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.150.321), which is a better starting point for reading than part II. Further, some additional useful results were given in the slightly earlier paper [C. N. Yang and C. P. Yang, Phys. Rev. 147, 303 (1966)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.147.303).